# Plot trajectory in R

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, datetime, trajectory

Does anyone knows a library/technique in R where you can plot a trajectory using multiple timesteps (points) where each point does have a lat/lon coordinate?
I have this data

```
x <- read.table("https://forms.naturwissenschaften.ch/imilast/_ERAinterim_1.5_1979_MTEX/ERAinterim_1.5_NH_M02_19790101_20121231_MTEX.txt?_ga=2.18919096.1825595846.1546710263-1112023567.1546710263", sep="", fill = T, nrows = 1000,
                     header = F, skip = 2) # download only the first 1000 rows
colnames(x) <- c("Code","CycloneNo","StepNo","DateI10","Year","Month","Day","Time","LongE","LatN","Intensity1","Intensity2","Intensity3")
```

Until now I was using a library called esd (developed by Meteo Norway) - which is very nice ([github/metno/esd](https://github.com/metno/esd)), where there was a function (read.imilast and plot.trajectory), however, that is not the greatest visualization tool). Also, I tried using openair (trajPlot) but that was quite hard to optimize for my data.

I want to plot each trajectory (column `CycloneNo`) under a different color if possible and more important, to have like a start and end point for each trajectory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ggplot2` and `dplyr` should be enough for this. They're general, not specialised packages, but once you get used to them, they're very versatile.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)    
x <- x %>% filter(Code!=90) ##Just cleaning to remove those 'NA' rows

##Label start and end points
x <- x %>% group_by(CycloneNo) %>% mutate(state=case_when(StepNo==1 ~ "Start",
                                                         StepNo==max(StepNo)~ "End",
                                                         T ~ "NA")) 

##Create visualisation
ggplot(x,aes(x=LongE,y=LatN,group=CycloneNo,color=as.factor(CycloneNo))) + ##This maps the x and y axes and tells the plot to group and colour based on the CycloneNo variable
      geom_path() + ##This will actually then plot the coloured trajectories
      geom_point(data=x %>% filter(state!="NA"),aes(fill=state,shape=state),size=4 ) + ##This adds markers to denote the start and end points of each trajectory
      geom_text(data=x %>% filter(state=="Start"),aes(label=CycloneNo),color="black",vjust=0,hjust=1) + ##This labels the start of each trajectory with the 'CycloneNo' variable
      guides(colour=F) ##This removes the legend for the cyclone numbers (as it's not really necessary/helpful in this case)
```

You would need to apply transformations on cyclones 29, 36 and 46 to deal with them crossing the 180degree longitude boundary.